# How to get name of second last folder in linux

Tags: linux, command

I have to write a shell script in linux in which i have to pull the name of the second last folder of the given path. For example:-

```
/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3
```

How can i get only the name of second last folder "folder2" using a command?

```
Note: My shell script is placed at root (/var/www/html)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}' <<< "/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3"
```

Alternatively, call `basename` on the `dirname`.

```
basename "$(dirname /var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3)"
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sed to get it:

```
export some_path="/var/www/html/folder1/folder2/folder3"
export folder_place2=`echo $some_path  | sed -e "s/.*\/\([^/]*\)\/[^/]*/\1/"`
echo $folder_place2
```