# bash equivalent to tcsh modifiers for extracting path components

Tags: bash, tcsh

In tcsh I can extract second path element from the end of path by following way

```
cd /some/long/directory/structure/path/
set x=`pwd`
echo ${x:h:h:t}
directory
```

How can I do the same in bash?

I mean , does bash also have this kind of modifiers?

Comment: This is very closely related to, if not outright duplicative of, [How to get name of second last folder in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13267126/how-to-get-name-of-second-last-folder-in-linux) or [How to get the last part of dirname in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23162299/how-to-get-the-last-part-of-dirname-in-bash).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It is not. This question is about modifiers and not about "how to extract n's element from path"

Comment: However, such "modifiers" (in bash, these are all referred to as [parameter expansion](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) forms) are all subsets of means to achieve your goal. Thus, the preexisting Q&A entries linked above *do* discuss them -- see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44350542/14122) for an example.

Comment: And frankly, if you're restricting your answer from "how do I do X in bash?" to "how do I do X in bash using a direct analog to syntax Y?", I question whether that question is *practical* in nature, as required by [our on-topic definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). (If you know *a* means to do X, it's fair to ask for a faster one or a terser one, but one that's different *just because*... well, what's the practical point?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ... and frankly, yes Charles, this question is very practical. Otherwise I wasn't asked it :-) . Thanks to jhnc , chepner and many other stackoverflow users who published the solution and not tried to show how "smart" they are regarding to "our topic definition". Guys - you really helped me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a non-interactive bash script, history expansion commands as in @chepner's answer won't normally be available. However, you do have parameter expansions like:

```
$ cd /some/long//directory///structure/path/
$ set x=$(pwd)
$ echo $x
/some/long/directory/structure/path
$ y=${y%/*/*}      # each /* is equivalent to one :h
$ y=${y##*/}       # equivalent to :t
$ echo $y
directory
```

Comment: History expansion isn't line editing, and can be enabled for non-interactive shells (though I wouldn't recommend it).

Answer (score 3):

The `csh`-style modifiers can be used with history expansion (unsurprisingly, because history expansion was borrowed from `csh`).

```
$ cd /some/long/directory/structure/path/
$ echo !!:1:h:h:t
echo directory
directory
```

`!!:1` selects word 1 (counting from zero) of the previous command, so the argument to `cd`.

(`echo directory` appears on standard error because the shell defaults to displaying the result of history expansion before actually executing the resulting command.)

Comment: Is there is a way to get this output not in standard error or i need to use redirection trick?

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /some/long/path/somewhere
x=$PWD
basename "$(dirname "$x")"
>  path
```

dirname gets the absolute path of the parent folder of the argument. basename gets the name of the argument.

Edit: remembered the much better way than I was doing before.

Comment: `$PWD` shouldn't have trailing slashes. If it may, `y=${x%%/}` will strip any. Perhaps worth annotating in your answer what equates to `:h` and what to `:t`

Comment: @jhnc, remembered a better way

Comment: You mean `basename "$(dirname "$x")"`, right? Just `x` doesn't look at the variable's value, and without the quotes, directory names with spaces will misbehave.

Comment: that's not exactly bash though. could just as well feed it into perl if you're going to do it that way. :p